# thredded styles are not being overwritten

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the "thredded" gem for the forum, which is the nuts btw. However I am having a hard time overriding the styles. The [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/thredded/0.15.4#Styles) offers:

```
// application.scss
$thredded-brand: #9c27b0;
@import "thredded";
```

as an example. I would welcome any help with understanding why, having copied in the information exactly as above, it is not working.

I am also trying to put my navbar on top of the navbar that comes installed with thredded.

any any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

Comment: Have you tried moving the line `$thredded-brand: #9c27b0;` below the import line?

Comment: hi, i have now tried it but no dice man. it says in the documentation to override the variables before importing the thredded styles, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: You're correct, I hadn't seen the documentation or have any experience with "thredded". I updated your question to include a link to reference the documentation you're talking about.

Comment: One more question, you say in your question you copied the information exactly as above. Am I correct assuming you also changed the extension of your *application.css* to *application.scss*?

Comment: hi, yes i had already changed it to application.scss. thank you for adding the link.

my file is in app/stylesheets/application.scss

i havent seen anywhere else to change the css. im still a bit stuck

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the application layout for this to work.

See https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/thredded/0.15.4#Application_layout